# Google Calendar API fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode not working

Tags: php, api, calendar, google-calendar-api, access-token

I am stucked 3 days ago with Google Calendar API, I am new in Google API.
First of all I want to get events from users calendar.
I went through on the install process a few times, but my code always stop at fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode function.
Probably I miss something really obvious, but I can't figure out what is wrong.

In web root I created a new folder for testing with 2 basic file from Google install site.

My php files:

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'path/googleapi/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('path/googleapi/credentials.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
$client->setRedirectUri('https://site/google/oauth2callback.php');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setPrompt("consent");
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
$auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
var_dump($auth_url);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  var_dump($_SESSION);
} else {
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```

oauth2callback.php:

```
<?php

require_once 'path/googleapi/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('path/googleapi/credentials.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('https://site/google/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
$client->setAccessType("offline");

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
var_dump($_GET['code']);
  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
  echo "<br>token:<br>";
  var_dump($token);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'https://site/google/';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

?>
```

I got redirected to Google's site, once I grant permission I am redirected to the oauth2callback.php
In oauth2callback.php I can see the var_dump output for the code, but no further output, which means no response from fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode function.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: have you created a billing profile for your project? Even if your code works, google really cares about having everything in place in case you have to be charged.

Comment: Are you getting any error message like a ```403``` or ```400```? Could you try to log the response if you can and let me know what is outputing?